# Error while trying to place string array into string array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
string &parse(string str,int from){
   string *data=new string[6];
    ....
    ....
   return *data;
}


int main(){
string data[6];
data=parse(str,18); //ERR: std::string must be a modifiable lvalue
}
```

I got the error above, I'm thinking to create operator=, is that correct?
If so, I tried this

`string operator=(const string& other){} //ERR: operator= must be a member function`

but I get another error.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: data is a string array, parse returns a reference to a string. What are you expecting this assignment to do?!?

Comment: should I define the function as string* parse(..) then return *data?

Comment: Unless you're trying to learn how to use arrays and pointers, a beginner is better off using standard containers to manipulate collections of strings. See `vector` class accessible including `<vector>`.

Comment: So how I can i do that? without vector

Comment: The code is very confused, and I can't work out what you're actually trying to do. You are trying to copy one array to another? If so I'd forget it and use vectors instead. You cannot return an array from a function, it's just not allowed.

Comment: Im trying to return string array from function (using its new address), then placing it outside of the function in string array.

Comment: @MikeL Well as I said, returning an array from a function is just not allowed in C++. Returning a vector is allowed though.

Comment: what about pointer to array?

Comment: @MikeL a pointer to a dynamically allocated array is allowed (See my answer). A pointer to a statically allocated local array has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse()` returns a reference to a `std::string`, so when you dereference the local array of strings, you are returning a reference to the first string of the array.
In `main()` you are assigning that reference to an array of strings, which has no sense at all.
The best option to achieve what you are trying to do is to use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v(6);

    ...

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> data;

    data = parse();
}
```

The vector is returned by value, but there is no performance issue, because the vector can be eassilly moved instead of copied.

If you cannot use `std::vector` (because you are trying to learn and understand dynamic arrays, for example), you could return a pointer to the dynamic array which you allocated at the beggining of `parse()`:

```
std::string* parse()
{
    std::string* strs = new std::string[6];

    ...

    return strs;
}

int main()
{
    std::string* data;

    data = parse();

    ...

    delete[] data; //Don't forget to release the array memory!
}
```

Comment: That last statement is wrong, because if you look at his code the array in parse is allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Borgleader thanks, I didn't see the `new` statement, I was thinking about a local static array. Fixed.

Comment: @jhon The goal of this solutions (The easilly-moveable `std::vector` and the dynamic array) is to avoid the unnecesary and expensive copy.

Answer (score 4):

Your code really needs refactoring, dont use arrays of strings - use vector-s of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> parse(string str,int from){
   std::vector<std::string> data(6);
    ....
    ....
   return data;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> data=parse(str,18);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do it without vectors ( you should use vectors, but anyway.. ) you have to get your types right:

string*: pointer to string (can be several strings next to each other), string&: reference to single string.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// return type is "pointer to string", not "reference to string"
string* parse(string str,int from){
   string *data=new string[6];
   return data; // do not apply the *-operator here.
}

int main(){
string* data; // don't mention the size here. ( probably the error you got. )
data=parse("hmm..",18); // assign the result ( pointer ) to data
delete[] data; // don't leak memory
}
```

however i suggest you read up on pointers, references and what happens when you apply the *-operator. string * does *not* just mean "array of strings"